# Replaying actions in Redux devtools will generate new actions with RxJS

Tags: redux, rxjs, redux-devtools, redux-devtools-extension

So basically My `Angular2` application is using `ngrx` and `rxjs`. And also I'm using `Redux DevTools` chrome extention for debugging purpose.

The thing is when I tried to replay all the actions in `Redux DevTools`, it always generates new actions automatically. I think the reason is because I'm using a lot of Observables and Subscriptions from `rxjs` to listen to any store updates and dispatch new actions based on that, and since replaying actions will update the store, it will trigger all those subscriptions. So my question is, is it possible to prevent new actions being generated from replaying actions?

Comment: That's an interesting 'flaw' in the redux pattern. Do you have a simple example?